# Definition Query returning No Results using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, definition-query

I have a fairly large contour feature class (about 500,000 contours) and I'm trying to select out just the 0.5m contours from the set. I can see from the attribute table that there's plenty of such contours but when I apply a definition query to select out these features it returns zero results. I've used the same method on a couple of other feature classes and it seemed to work fine. I'm wondering if anyone's encountered this before or knows of a work around.

This is in ArcGIS Pro 2.9.

The query is simply `Contour = 0.5` and the datatype of the Contour Field is Double.

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427479/definition-query-returning-no-results#comment697490_427479), multiplying the target value to remove the decimal and then casting as an integer seemed to solve the problem.

I modified my SQL statement to read:

```
cast((Contour * 10) as int) = 5
```

and it worked like a charm.

Comment: An alternative approach is `contour > 0.49 and contour <0.51`.